# While loop won't break (JAVA)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, break

This is the code:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {

    System.out.print("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.next();

    if (word.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    } 

}
```

Even though I have that `break;` within the `if` statement it still runs even after I enter in a blank String. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your reader declared & assigned?

Comment: First, learn how to debug

Comment: `Scanner::next` returns the next *complete* token from  a Scanner. A *complete* token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. Essentially, `Scanner::next`  waits till it gets a _complete_ token. Currently, `Scanner::next` is blocked while waiting for input to scan. so it's never getting to the `if` statement. just do a simple `println` before and after the `if` statement and you'll notice this behaviour.

Comment: I don't think `Scanner.next()` can ever return an empty string (using the default delimiter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "reader" is a Scanner instance, try

```
String word = reader.nextLine();
```

That way the scanner will return when you press enter with an empty string.

Comment: While this indeed fixes the problem, it does not explain why OPs code does not work. I think OP wanted to know the **why** in first place. So you could improve the quality by also adding an explanation. Also, to extend the answer, please carefully read the [official documentation of Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), it often solves such problems immediately.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your string is blank? You pressed enter without typing anything? How do you know the reader didn't put the new line characters into the string causing it not to be empty? Put a print of the length of the read-in string right after you read it; you'll probably find out pretty quickly why isEmpty() returns false..